# Renaming tag for renamed js library

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

Is there a way to formally submit a change of tag name to moderators? The tag in question is `redux-simple-router` which about a month ago officially switched to `react-router-redux`. It seems like it was done to follow the very closely coupled `react-router` library.

If not renaming it, is there a way for a moderator to create a synonym?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To ask for a tag to be renamed, you should create a [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) post on the site's meta. On Stack Overflow, it looks like you should also add the [`retag-request`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/retag-request) tag. *Make the case* that it should be done - just asking for something to happen is not particularly likely to make it so. A moderator might very well unilaterally create a synonym.

If a synonym doesn't just appear by moderator's order, you can propose it yourself if you have at least a score of 5 in that tag (and 2500 rep, which you have on Stack Overflow). Just go to the new tag's `/synonyms` page (a link to which appears in its excerpt box).

[image: link to the synonyms page]
There, type the tag that should be merged into it and press the Suggest button. If you did your meta post well, other people with a tag score of 5 or above can vote for the synonym.

[image: the suggest button]